# Spinner values to Database

Tags: android, database, spinner

I can't make the spinner write to the database. I read the docs about spinner, but I'm definitely doing something wrong. Can someone give some advice?
I've read many tutorials but I'm getting confused. How can I make the spinner write to database in the onClick in which I have already on input and want to add 1 more including the spinner.

```
  import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.widget.AdapterView;
    import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
    import android.widget.Button;
    import android.widget.EditText;
    import android.widget.Spinner;
    import android.widget.Toast;
    
    import java.util.ArrayList;
    import java.util.List;
    
    public class AddActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener {
    
        DatabaseHelper mylogsDB;
        Button btn_save;
        EditText etHours;
        Spinner etShift;
    
        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_add);
            etHours = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);
            etShift = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner);
            btn_save = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_save);
            mylogsDB = new DatabaseHelper(this);
    
            AddData();
    
            // Spinner click listener
            etShift.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
    
            // Spinner Drop down elements
            List<String> categories = new ArrayList<>();
            categories.add("Πρωί");
            categories.add("Μεσημέρι");
            categories.add("Νύχτα");
    
            // Creating adapter for spinner
            ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, categories);
    
            // Drop down layout style - list view with radio button
            dataAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    
            // attaching data adapter to spinner
            etShift.setAdapter(dataAdapter);
        }
    
            public void onItemSelected (AdapterView <?> parent, View view,int position, long id) {
                // On selecting a spinner item
                String item = parent.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();
    
                // Showing selected spinner item
                Toast.makeText(parent.getContext(), "Έχετε επιλέξει: " + item, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    
    
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        }
    
        public void AddData() {
            btn_save.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    String hours = etHours.getText().toString();
                    String shift = etShift.getSelectedItem().toString();
    
                    boolean insertData = mylogsDB.addData(hours, shift);
    
                    if (insertData == true) {
                        Toast.makeText(AddActivity.this, "Η αποθήκευση ολοκληρώθηκε επιτυχώς.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    } else {
                        Toast.makeText(AddActivity.this, "Ώχ,Κάτι πήγε στραβά.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to keep the selected value from the `Spinner` and then use it in the method of which you use to insert into database

Also you should call `AddData();` in your `btn_save` `onClick` event !

```
public class AddActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener {

    DatabaseHelper mylogsDB;
    Button btn_save;
    EditText etHours;
    Spinner etShift;
    private String spinnerSelectedItem;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_add);
        etHours = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);
        etShift = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner);
        btn_save = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_save);
        mylogsDB = new DatabaseHelper(this);

        btn_save.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                AddData();
            }
        });

        // Spinner click listener
        etShift.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);

        // Spinner Drop down elements
        List<String> categories = new ArrayList<>();
        categories.add("Πρωί");
        categories.add("Μεσημέρι");
        categories.add("Νύχτα");

        // Creating adapter for spinner
        ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, categories);

        // Drop down layout style - list view with radio button
        dataAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);

        // attaching data adapter to spinner
        etShift.setAdapter(dataAdapter);
    }

    public void onItemSelected (AdapterView <?> parent, View view,int position, long id) {
        // On selecting a spinner item
        spinnerSelectedItem = parent.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();

        // Showing selected spinner item
        Toast.makeText(parent.getContext(), "Έχετε επιλέξει: " + spinnerSelectedItem, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }


    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }

    public void AddData() {

        String hours = etHours.getText().toString();
        //spinnerSelectedItem should have a value

        if(!hours.equals("") && !spinnerSelectedItem.equals("")){
            boolean insertData = mylogsDB.addData(hours, spinnerSelectedItem);
            if (insertData == true) {
                Toast.makeText(AddActivity.this, "Η αποθήκευση ολοκληρώθηκε επιτυχώς.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(AddActivity.this, "Ώχ,Κάτι πήγε στραβά.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }else{
            //do something
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Gives error in this line: ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, categories); says cannot find declarstion. AND with equals inside btn_save.

Comment: Gives error in this line: ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, categories); says cannot find declaration in(this). AND with equals inside btn_save.

Comment: @KostasKoustoulidis show me how you use this statement, edit you post and add this part of code [in which you use that statment] at the end of your post

Comment: Now I'm using my mobile so it's a little bit hard to type. But i copied your code inside AddActivity.I think that i should make it AddActivity.this?

Comment: @KostasKoustoulidis That is not enough, you have to create an `onClick` listener for `btn_save` and then call `AddData();` in that event

Comment: Didn't i do that already? There is an onclick listener for hours which i want to use for spinner to.

Comment: @KostasKoustoulidis I have edited my answer, this is the correct way i was talking about, when button is clicked `AddData()` should be called

Comment: Still gives error on cannot resolve symbol (item)  and cannot resolve symbols (equal).

Comment: @KostasKoustoulidis check now again

Comment: @KostasKoustoulidis it's `equals` I just made an error while writing

Comment: look at this.this is the output i get after build. [link](http://www.4shared.com/photo/z0eE2BO_ba/Picture.html) there is no spinner value.Maybe i must make listView with rows?

Comment: Well i looked inside my db file and its storing the values perfectly. I'm marking this as answer. It's a list view problem now. Thanks a lot @Atef

Comment: @KostasKoustoulidis you are welcome and remember you can always post a new question ;)